# VSCode autocomplete for OpenMP

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, openmp

Is there way to get the autocomplete functions from OpenMp for 'c' files inside VSCode.

I'm currently using

```
#include <omp.h>
```

But this shows a red-underline with the error that imports are not found. Using the `-fopenmp` with `gcc` compiles my executable, by the way.

Comment: Do you have a custom include path that your editor is not aware of?

Comment: I hope not. Is there way to check where the omp.h file is for gcc? Because gcc compiles fine. Ill try to check.

Comment: Found the file. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/ So shall I include this in the include path.?

Comment: That's a pretty standard location. Did OMP install there?

Comment: I didnot install omp specifically using my package manager. It must have already installed along with gcc. I didnot know that gcc installs in that location as well. I added that location to my vscode include path. Now it works flawlessly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's worth adding that as an answer to close out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To get auto-completions from any Header File:

You need to its path to option **"C_Cpp.default.includePath"** of the C/C++ extension on VScode. *(This would only work for the microsoft extension)*

You could search for header using:
`find /usr -name omp.h` and then add the appropriate path inside your **Settings.json**

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/",
],
```